# Concatenated html breaks the page due to unclosed tags

Tags: html

Throughout my tenure as a developer this has always cropped up, and I am wondering if there is any simple solution to the problem.

Let's say that we have a repeater which outputs contents of a database. One of these columns contains HTML, but I do not want so show ALL of this HTML, only a portion.

If I concatenate it to show a summary, there are obviously unclosed tags which break the rest of the page.

I do not want to strip the HTML formatting out of the string. I would really like a way of closing any open tags within the output before moving onto the next record. jQuery considered.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Example source code, FWIW

```
<div id="MyColumn">
    <!-- start of database string -->
    <div>This is my string. There are many li
    <!-- end of database string -->
</div>
```

Comment: And why did you not post any source code?

Comment: Do you know the structure of this `html` beforehand? If you do you might be able to add the whole `html` then remove the unwanted nodes via `javascript` afterwards.

Comment: There is no need for source code. It's not difficult to understand.

@Sir Celcius: No, the HTML could be anything within this field.

Comment: @user2992508 The fact that it's not difficult to understand doesn't mean that some code wouldn't make it easier. We also would like to see how you are doing it now so we can help you, giving you some unexplained code that do the job wouldn't help anyone.

Comment: There is always need for source code, it makes the question easier to grasp. Anyways, if you can't know the structure it will be complicated. The thing is, from the moment your DOM gets messed up, it gets complicated to clean it up. I'm at a loss here, but I'm quite certain you will need to treat the code before adding it.

Comment: Updated with example source code

Comment: It is clearer already. What do you mean by "only a portion". Do you want to get rid of `n` lines/characters before the end or show only the `n` first characters or something similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any Tools To Find Missing HTML Tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307178/any-tools-to-find-missing-html-tags)

Comment: @SirCelsius BY only a portion I mean I would like to show no more than, say, 100 characters. I would perhaps do this by outputting LEFT(column, 100) from a stored procedure.

Comment: Do you need the html to be rendered?

Comment: As much as possible, yes. As I mentioned, I do not want to strip the HTML out completely (I already have a function to do this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing the point here, but how about putting all your html strings into individual iframes?

See example.
http://jsfiddle.net/r0xyk7mr/1/

```
<div id="MyColumn">
    <!-- start of database string -->
    <div id="dbcontents"></div>
    <!-- end of database string -->
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var dbstrings = ["<div>This is my string. There are <b>many li", "<div>This is my string. There"];

for(var i=0;i<dbstrings.length;i++){
    var newIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    newIframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(dbstrings[i]);
    document.getElementById("dbcontents").appendChild(newIframe);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the closest I've come to finding a solution, but the javascript breaks all over the place due to the content being loaded in. There are double quotes, apostrophes and line breaks, all of which have some effect. I have used server-side encoding to stop the javascript from erroring, but that simply outputs the textualised HTML source as the contents of the iFrame, rather than formatting it.

Comment: why did you go with iframe on this ? ^^ Why not just a regular (more accepted) DIV element ?